# RN Horizontal pull to refresh

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, pull-to-refresh

I have a horizontally scrolling React-Native FlatList that I implemented by setting the "horizontal" prop to true and it works perfectly but now I want to add pull to refresh and I cannot get this to work.

I have added "refresing" and "onRefresh" props which do their work properly. The only problem is that FlatList implements a vertical pull to refresh which is very weird when scrolling horizontally. In both Android and iOS you have to pull down from the top to start refreshing but that does not make sense because when you are at the end of the list you want to pull from the left. On iOS it is also much worse because the whole inside of the FlatList can now also move vertically.

Is there any settings I can try to make it work properly or any way I can manually implement a horizontal pull to refresh?

Comment: could you try to make an Expo snack and share the link for searching any solution?

Comment: same exact problem here. Ideally I want onEndReached to work for both left and right scrolling in a horizontal FlatList.

Comment: Have you found any proper solution  @Gerbus ?